# How do I store C++ variables in an INI, CFG, or XML file?

Tags: c++, xml, visual-studio, config, ini

My script.cpp file contains the following lines:

```
bool mod_enabled = true;        //Enable/Disable
BYTE display_delay = 15;        //Redisplay delay
```

Ideally, the values for mod_enabled and display_delay should be pulled from an external configuration file which the user can edit. (The code itself is being compiled into an GTAV ASI plugin, which runs at the start of the game.)

I have no need for saving or changing these values mid-game. What is the simplest solution?

Comment: Convert them to a string?! e.g. `mod_enabled ? "true" : "false"`

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying. I need to store these values in an external configuration file and then read from that file when setting them in the project.

Comment: Read the file in as text (strings). Convert to internal representation. Write out as strings. eg. boolean to "true"/"false!"

Comment: Do you know how to read and write files?

Comment: I can simplify it and make every variable a byte instead of a bool, and do the whole thing in 1s and 0s, but again, I don't know how to pull information into the program from any kind of external file. I'm pretty new to C++ and after three hours of searching, I'm unable to find any documentation on how to do this.

Comment: immibis - I do not. I know how to do it in C# using XDocument, but not C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the solution is simple.

INI file (XXX.ini):

```
[Settings]
mod_enabled=1           // Enable/Disable
display_delay=1         //Redisplay delay
```

CODE:

```
bool mod_enabled = GetPrivateProfileInt("Settings", "mod_enabled", 1, "./XXX.ini") != 0;
int display_delay = GetPrivateProfileInt("Settings", "display_delay", 15, "./XXX.ini");
```

The !=0 is necessary to cast an integer to a boolean. Otherwise, Visual Studio will give you errors.